# NodeJS get request. Cannot access JSON elements

Tags: json, node.js, get

I have the following code inside a get request in NodeJS

```
response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log(chunk);
    JSON.parse(chunk);
    console.log("ch"+chunk.product.productId);
    responseData+=chunk;
});
```

The first console.log prints the entire response, which is a JSON in form of a string:

```
{"product":[{"defaultProductUrl":"http:\/\/www.zappos.com\/product\/7306789","defaultImageUrl":"http:\/\/www.zappos.com\/images\/z\/2\/1\/3\/2\/5\/4\/2132548-p-DETAILED.jpg","productId":"7306789","productName":"Pro Short","brandId":"1630","brandName":"CW-X"}],"statusCode":"200"}
```

The second one however throws an error:

```
console.log("ch"+chunk.product.productId);

TypeError: Cannot read property 'productId' of undefined
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (c:\Users\Udai\Desktop\Zappos\server.js:78:38)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (_stream_readable.js:746:14)
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:408:10)
    at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:404:5)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:165:9)
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:127:10)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnBody [as onBody] (http.js:141:22)
    at Socket.socketOnData [as ondata] (http.js:1584:20)
```

Any ideas on what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can be, and often are, more than a single `chunk` of `'data'` in a readable stream. You'll want to make sure you have all of them (even if there is only 1) and perform processing once it's come to an [`'end'`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end).

```
var body = '';

response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    body += chunk.toString();
});

response.on('end', function () {
    // ...
});
```

You also need to store the result of `JSON.parse()` as it won't alter its argument.

```
var data = JSON.parse(body);
```

Then, from the `[...]` in the JSON, `data.product` will be an `Array` of `Object`s. So, you'll have to access an index of it to retrieve a `productId`.

```
console.log(data.product[0].productId);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to accumulate all of the data before you can run `JSON.parse` on it.  That is, keep accumulating the chunks in `responseData += chunk`, *then* run `JSON.parse`.  Otherwise, you could run `JSON.parse` on a string like: `{"prop":` followed by another chunk: `"value"}`.  Neither of those are valid JSON:

```
response.on("end", function () {
    console.log(JSON.parse(responseData));
});
```

Comment: if you see the first log statement, it is printing the entire json. That means chunk is actually the entire thing. Anyways I had tried your method as well on responseData and I am having the same issue

Comment: @UdaiArora see the other answer; essentially `JSON.parse` doesn't write to anything

Comment: Got it. The other answer basically builds on your point only.